# Conditoinal HTTP redirect IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis, iis-7.5

Currently I am redirecting all my http requests to HTTPS but now I want to add the condition that if URL contains 'admin' then redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS, how can i change the Rule to achieve this (e.g. http://www.example.com/admin/index.html) ?

```
 <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the url pattern to:

```
<match url=".*admin/.*" />
```

This seems to match your sample data OK in the IIS pattern match tool.

To match additional portions, e.g. profile you can alter the regular expression:

```
<match url=".*(admin|profile)/.*" />
```

If it is always going to start with `admin` or `profile` then you can tighten the regular expression to `^(admin|profile)/.*` (`^` means start of pattern, see [Defining a Pattern on this screen](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)).

Comment: Its working, 
another question: how can i add any other term in this rule e.g. redirect will work if 'admin' OR 'profile' is found in the URL ?